# Adding comma to separate multiple values from same column

Tags: reporting-services, expression, reportbuilder3.0

I have column with values like:

| Test |
| --- |
| test 1 |
| test 2 |
| test 3 |
| test 4 |

I am trying to put the values in a report in Microsoft Report Builder, but I don't want it listed in a table.  I would like it to be listed like below in a text box:

test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4

Is there an expression I can use? I have looked and tried Join and Split but haven't gotten the results I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this quite easily using `LOOKUPSET()` to get the values into an array and then using `JOIN()` to combine them into a string.

```
=Join(LookupSet(1, 1, Fields!myTestCol.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")
```

As we want all the rows from the dataset, I've used `1` in the first 2 arguments as a shortcut as 1 always equals 1 , every row in "DataSet1" will be returned. Then we `JOIN()` them with `", "` as the separator.

**Note:** `"DataSet1"` is the case-sensitive name of your dataset. You need to change this to match your dataset name or scope name (i.e. a RowGroup name) as required.

Comment: Thank you, that worked with getting the commas in between the values i needed.  But now im having an issue where its creating duplicate rows with the values, like:

|test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4|
|test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4|
|test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4|
|test 1, test 2, test 3, test 4|

seems to be creating as many duplicate rows as the values i have.  how do i go about removing the duplicate rows?

Comment: you can either `1.` put the expression in a text box that is not bound to a dataset, `2.` put the expression in a row that is outside your details rowgroup or `3.` group your tablix by some arbitrary value so you end up with a single row. At the moment the expression is being evaluated for each row in the dataset. If this does not help, create a new question and show your report design (in design mode) and also show what you want to achieve.

Comment: Perfect...the text box worked for me.  thanks for your help.